# Encryption at Rest: AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, encryption

I'm trying to use AWS Elasticsearch with "Encrytion at Rest". I configured this setting while creating the Elasticsearch domain in Elasticsearch services in AWS.

Lets consider there are two users named A and B.
I have created the KMS access policy where

1. User A is having permission to perform both es:* and kms:* actions
2. User B is having permission to perform only es:*,but not kms:* actions.

Here,
When ES Client is performing indexing and search some data as User A, Then it works.
When ES Client is performing indexing and search some data as User B, Then also it works. But I expect this to fail as User B don't have access to kms:encrypt or kms:decrypt and other kms actions.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have not used elastic search but used KMS quite often. KMS encryption and decryption is directly mapped to the IAM role for a service so for e.g if we want to decry-pt a secret encrypted using KSM the the role should have decrypt permission associated other it would be a `permission denied` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Encryption at Rest" is more of a systemic feature than a user-based one. The IAM Role used for Encryption at Rest applies more to the Service and is not meant to be used as an access control for users.

Hope this clears up the confusion here.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand "encryption at rest" in Amazon ES. I'm able to successfully do CRUD on ES irrespective of the users permissions for actions on KMS, which put me in a doubt that whether KMS encrypt, decrypt , generate data key actions are actually used by AWS ES or not. @DC.Skells

Comment: Aside from the information in the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/encryption-at-rest.html), here is what else I have found:

(This is older (2014), but should get you started)
https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Securing_Data_at_Rest_with_Encryption.pdf